# Count number of vowels in a string using Prolog

Tags: count, prolog

I am new in prolog, so i have to explain these code to my class teacher.
can someone please explain this code. Thanks

```
vowel(X):- member(X,[a,e,i,o,u]).
nr_vowel([],0).
nr_vowel([X|T],N):- vowel(X),nr_vowel(T,N1), N is N1+1,!.
nr_vowel([X|T],N):- nr_vowel(T,N).
```

output:

```
1 ?- nr_vowel([a,t,i,k],X).
X = 2.
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGfU5.jpg

Answer (score 1):

An explanation is indeed highly appropriate.

For example, let us ask the simplest question:

> **Which solutions are there at all?**

Try out out, by posting the **most general query** where all arguments are *fresh variables*:

```
?- nr_vowel(Ls, N).
Ls = [],
N = 0 ;
Ls = [a],
N = 1.
```

Hm! That's probably not what you wanted to describe!

So I change your code to:

```
nr_vowel([], 0).
nr_vowel([X|T], N):-
        vowel(X),
        nr_vowel(T,N1),
        N #= N1+1.
nr_vowel([X|T], N):-
        nr_vowel(T,N).
```

Then we get:

```
?- nr_vowel(Ls, N).
Ls = [],
N = 0 ;
Ls = [a],
N = 1 ;
Ls = [a, a],
N = 2 ;
Ls = [a, a, a],
N = 3 ;
etc.
```

Looks better!

How about **fair enumeration**? Let's see:

```
?- length(Ls, _), nr_vowel(Ls, N).
Ls = [],
N = 0 ;
Ls = [a],
N = 1 ;
Ls = [e],
N = 1 ;
Ls = [i],
N = 1 ;
Ls = [o],
N = 1 ;
Ls = [u],
N = 1 ;
Ls = [_2006],
N = 0 ;
Ls = [a, a],
N = 2 ;
Ls = [a, e],
N = 2 .
```

The first few answers all look promising, but what about `Ls = [_2006], N = 0`?

This is clearly **too general**!

You must make your program **more specific** to avoid this overly general answer.

Here is the problem in a nutshell:

```
?- nr_vowel([X], N), X = a.
X = a,
N = 1 ;
X = a,
N = 0.
```

*Whaaat?* `a` *is* a vowel, so why is `N = 0`??

Here is it in a smaller nutshell:

```
?- nr_vowel([a], 0).
true.
```

**Whaaaaat**??

I leave adding suitable **constraints** to the predicate as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

The code is simplistic in itself, all it does is count the number of vowels in a list (Guess that's quite evident to you).

Let's take your input as an example, the list is [a,t,i,k]

When you call **nr_vowel([a,t,i,k],Z)**, prolog searches for and unifies the query with the second nr_vowel clause, this is because it is the first clause with a non-empty list input.

Now, **vowel(a)** returns true, so prolog moves on to the next predicate, which calls **nr_vowel([t,i,k],Z)**. However this time, when prolog tries to unify it with the second nr_vowel, **vowel(t)** returns false, so it unifies it with the third clause and behaves similarly until the list is empty.

As soon as the list is empty, prolog unifies Z with 0 and starts coming up the recursion levels and does N=N+1 depending on if the caller predicate had a vowel or not, and as soon as it reaches the top of the recursive chain, Z is unified with the final value of N.

In short -

N=N+1 happens if the head of the list is a vowel

N=N i.e. no change occurs if head of list is NOT a vowel.